# empty keyword in Struts

Tags: jsp, struts2

Is there an `empty` keyword in Struts 2 (like in JSP)?

For example in JSP I write:

```
<c:if test="${empty var}">
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't do Struts2, but I can at least tell that the empty keyword is not part of JSP/JSTL, but of EL (those `${}` things). So if you use EL in Struts2 as well, you should be able to use the same EL keywords. And since Struts2 is *just* another JSP taglib (like JSTL), you *should* be able to use EL in it ...

Comment: I was looking for the struts-EL extension, and I came up with this page http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-el/index.html that states the "empty" tag is not supported in the Struts EL extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just test for null.

And to acheive the same effect than the JSTL empty keyword with strings (which means "null or empty"), you need two checks (yes it is tiresome):

```
<s:if test="foo != null && foo != ''">
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm doing now, but it's not the same check "empty" does. For example an array with no elements should be empty, a blank string like "     " too, etc. Thanks though.